# When i click on keyframe it automatically move on world origin why?

Tags: rigging, mixamo

I have append mixamo rigged character from other file and when I click for change or add keyframe it automatically move on last world origin position. Why?

I have reset my character with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> but not solve this problem.

Video to understand better.
https://screenrec.com/share/IsQXHCB7TS

Comment: Hello and welcome. You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information 
is visible in this page, instead of asking users go through links 
just to understand what you want to do. Please use the [edit] link at 
the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use 
the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed 
as part of your question. See
[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: If you have strips in the NLA editor, it will override the current animation.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have keyframes directly on the armature object. Maybe those send the object back to its original position. That happened to me many times when I started with blender. Try deleting them to see if that fixes the problem.

[image]